# Standard way to format names of applications/technologies/etc.?

Tags: discussion, edits

For example in a post I'm editing is the text:

> I’m submitting a form post using Angularjs (1.2.20) to Microsoft ASP.Net MVC 4:

There are various ways I could format it (keep in mind the idea is that a real situation could have paragraphs worth of references to the same name):

- **None**: maybe just standard English capitalization is good enough?:

  I’m submitting a form post using Angularjs (1.2.20) to Microsoft ASP.Net MVC 4:
- **Italic**: seems too weak, and you don't want tons of italic everywhere:

  I’m submitting a form post using *Angularjs (1.2.20)* to *Microsoft ASP.Net MVC 4*:
- **Bold**: seems maybe too strong, but this might be the way to go:

  I’m submitting a form post using **Angularjs (1.2.20)** to **Microsoft ASP.Net MVC 4**:
- **Inline Code**: does not seem right

  I’m submitting a form post using `Angularjs (1.2.20)` to `Microsoft ASP.Net MVC 4`:
- **Tags**: doesn't really work right and doesn't seem like this is intended

  I’m submitting a form post using [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) (1.2.20) to [microsoft-asp.net-mvc-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-asp.net-mvc-4):

Comment: FYI, the official way to capitalize the names of the two technologies is "AngularJS" and "Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 4" respectively.

Comment: @BoltClock OCD nerds `:P`

Comment: NONE. If articles and text were full of random formatting - as they so often are around here - they would become very difficult to read. You don't need to highlight keywords. The human brain will pick out the important bits from a question anyway, if it's written in a clear and concise way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is what I think:

#### Italics

> I’m submitting a form post using *Angularjs (1.2.20)* to *Microsoft ASP.Net MVC 4*:

In English publications, there is a convention that is *sometimes* used where cited works are italicized, like

- *The Wizard of Oz*
- *The Avengers*
- *Yellow Submarine*

In the software industry, however, this is basically *never* done. So don't do it. It's annoying.

#### Bold

> I’m submitting a form post using **Angularjs (1.2.20)** to **Microsoft ASP.Net MVC 4**:

I would avoid using bold to highlight the use of library names. If you feel that you have to emphasize library names with bold in your posts, then it's probably a sign that *you're not writing clearly enough*.

#### Inline code

> I’m submitting a form post using `Angularjs (1.2.20)` to `Microsoft ASP.Net MVC 4`:

**STOP USING CODE FORMATTING FOR THINGS THAT AREN'T CODE!!!**

[image: Y U USE CODE FORMATTING?!]

#### Tags

> I’m submitting a form post using [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) (1.2.20) to [microsoft-asp.net-mvc-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-asp.net-mvc-4):

I would avoid using tags to emphasize code libraries in what you write. Tags mess up the vertical spacing between lines, e.g. [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) making it harder to read long posts. Plus, your post should already have tags in the tag section (if it's a question), so there's no need to add them to the post body.

Did I mention that tags, e.g. [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), mess up the vertical spacing between lines, making it harder to read long posts with many paragraphs? [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs).

#### Summary

So basically, **don't use any special formatting at all**. If you feel like you need to emphasize the names of code libraries in your posts, then like I said earlier, it's probably a sign that *you're not writing clearly enough*, and you should work on improving the clarity of the post *without* having to resort to visually emphasizing library/framework names.

Comment: "it's probably a sign that *you suck at writing* clear posts" Ouch.

Comment: @BoltClock toned it down.

Comment: I don't disagree but isn't this answer a little hypocritical?

Comment: @Ben **too much bold?**

Comment: Or italics....?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need additional formatting. If you think you do, you're wrong. If you find yourself using multiple types of formatting for ordinary words your post is over-formatted. Don't use "standard English capitalisation" though; these are product names, capitalise them in the same way as the product.

If you're using a technology, put it in the tags, that's what they're there for. Only enumerate it again if you need to.

P.S. (I recognise you didn't want to) but people who use code highlighting for anything other than code are evil; like really naughty.